# Wallpaper Engine, insight on customizing Audio Visualizer's rendering

Tags: javascript, audio, wallpaper

Since my last post I've made some headway in my Wallpaper-- fixing a lot of my prior issues

Today though I'd like some direction if anyone has it:

The last widget that I'm working on is an Audio Visualizer. My pursuit of desiring uniqueness isn't without its issues however (... can you really be a programmer without this attribute?). Here's the reference that I am modeling, a visualizer I made a few weeks ago in After Effects. https://youtu.be/cHweVjmBmP4

In the "limitations" of Javascript and Wallpaper Engine, is there anyway that I can replicate these sharps bends and curves in my output? I at first believed that a variable employing the arcTo() method would help out here.. but it's unclear to me what coordinates would be used for my tangents. And what formula would help explain the affected data.

Here's the code as it stands. Thanks to [Michael Fedora](https://steamcommunity.com/id/MikeFed/) for writing such an accessible code. I have learned so much about algorithms from reading and even more by testing things on my own. I'll keep trying to figure this out but any help is endlessly appreciated!

```
    let i, x = 0, y = center + scale*data[0]*0.33;   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    for(i = 0; i < 63; i++) {
        x += width;
        y = center + scale * data[i];
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    x += width;
    y = center + scale * (data[63] + data[127]) * 0.5;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    x += width;
    y = center + scale * data[126];
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);

    x = 128*width, y = center + scale*data[64]*0.33;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    for(i = 64;i < 127; i++) {
        x -= width;
        y = center + scale * data[i];
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);




    }
}

function renderLine(ctx, color) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    if(glob.bloom) {
        ctx.shadowBlur = glob.bloomRadius;
        ctx.shadowColor = color;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see curves in your AE example, but a long polyline with the join style set to round (so angles get round corners).

I don't know about Wallpaper Engine in particular, but that looks like [regular Canvas stuff, in which you can do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineJoin)

```
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
```

The examples in the linked MDN page do better at explaining the join styles than I ever could.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! "Curves" and "sharp bends" happened to be my go-to shorthands for describing the depicted irregular triangle style. 

I'll see where I can go with this! The main obstacle now remains the coordinates

Comment: Your AE example looks like it has frequency bins alternating between positive and negative Y magnitudes. That might help you out.

Comment: Thank you again! Funnily enough, I was just seeking this sort of thing out. Going to try and find ways that the browser can understand this. Your form of phrasing has me thinking of the possibilities.. you are appreciated!

Comment: No worries. Here's a little Codesandbox that might help! https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-meitner-fkj3y

Comment: I'm almost certain that this is what I have to do! Gosh, you are a life saver! If I'm not misunderstanding, the code here is trying to find every odd number in the frequency bin / audio array right? Your help from earlier nudged me into that direction.. I think I am now just finding ways to translate that into the current code! I'm sure this'll aid me as a reference. Thank you so much again

Comment: No, it just moves the points up or down whether nor not the bin's index is odd or even. Try changing `? -1 : 1` to `? 1 : 1` :)

Comment: In each new comment, I experience the same amazement that a child does when a magician pulls a rabbit out of their hat. Telling that I was seeing what I wanted to see haha.. That seems much more applicable to what I have! I’ll get back to you if it works out!